# Run time 1004 error when selecting multiple rows to paste vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select multiple rows to paste onto a new sheet but am getting a 1004 error. I think I have a dimension mismatch or a syntax error. Here is the line of code that is giving me issues:

```
             ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(Offsetcount - Rowoffset, 0), ActiveSheet.Cells(Offsetcount, 0)).EntireRow.Select
```

I can paste more if need be.

Comment: What does your row look like, is there an error code etc. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column in Excel is column 1 not column 0.

So try

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(Offsetcount - Rowoffset, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(Offsetcount, 1)).EntireRow.Select
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was 0 based for some reason. 

Now my code copies the correct number of rows but always just the top X number, so I need to play with the offset more.